# Problems with loading a KML file into my Google Map

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know why loading a KML file into my sencha touch google map zooms it all the way into the ocean off the coast of Africa?

http://sencha1.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test.kml

```
{
                            xtype: 'map',
                            mapOptions: {
                                    center : new google.maps.LatLng(33.573724,-85.101621),
                                    zoom : 16
                            },
                            listeners: {
                                    maprender : function(comp, map){
                                            var routeLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://sencha1.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test.kml');
                                            routeLayer.setMap(map);
                                            //alert("hello!");
                                    }
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Looks like hosting a file in your public folder on dropbox is a quick and easy way for those actively developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must be wrong with kml file or file is unaccessible (it has to be on publicly avaliable link).

Comment: I supplied a link, are you able to download the file?

Comment: NO all I got is **** 403 Forbidden
Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied
RequestId: A6D3FFBFBC4D2674
HostId: 9n5kQ0hgEmsvwEr01+eGQqqataYfolbSF337jfgi6eqbbPV4+k79jK32qRgqDw4d ****

Comment: Right, but the file still downloaded to my browser..are you aware of an easy way to host a public accessible KML file? I used the Google URL in one of their examples and it rendered perfectly. I suppose that's the issue.

Comment: It is just an ordinary txt file, so every host should be able to made it publicly avaliable. Try with freehostia or even with host it on youre computer from apache + noip service. I belive even dropbox will do